# Empty $_POST & $_FILE

Tags: php

I know that this question has been asked many times before but I've searched through the already existing topics and I can't seem to find anyone with the exact same problem as me, so sorry in advance if it's already been covered.

My system is locally hosted and I have full read/write access to the tmp folder.

---

This is the relevant phpinfo from `phpinfo()`:

```
file_uploads    On
post_max_size   20M
upload_max_filesize 10M
memory_limit    128M
```

---

This is the form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group" action="./? action=create&id='.$id.'&next=1" method="post">
    <label class="sr-only" for="thumbnail">Thumbnail image</label>              
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="thumbnail" name="thumbnail" placeholder="Select the album thumbnail">
<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" />
</form>
```

---

And when I print the `var_dump` of `$_POST['thumbnail']` I get

```
null
```

Comment: `$_FILES['thumbnail']`.

Comment: Where is your php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change From

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group" action="./? action=create&id='.$id.'&next=1" method="post">
```

To

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group" action="./? action=create&id=<?php echo $id;?>&next=1" method="post">
```

Then `var_dump($_FILES['thumbnail']);`

`$_FILES` is An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

Comment: This worked thanks. Is there any reason why $_POST dosen't work in this scenario?

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm glad it works for you. Why you use `$id` in your action. For your question I have updated my answer.

Comment: The form is in a php file being echo'd so that wasn't the problem. Thanks for the answer.